# Storing [MLMultiArray] in Realm?

Tags: swift, realm, coreml

For context, I am making a face recognition model that will take 120 images of the student/user and converts them into MLMultiArray which is a Float32 1 x 120 matrix. The problem I am facing is that I cant store/persist 120 MLMultiArray in Realm as it does not conform to protocol 'RealmCollectionValue'

For reference, This is the student object that I want to store in Realm.

```
    class Student: Object {
        @objc dynamic var regNo : String = ""
        @objc dynamic var faceMatrix = List<MLMultiArray>()
    }
```

I have to store this matrix in Realm and then use it later to recognize faces by taking checking the distance between the new matrix and the one stored in Realm.

Each MLMultiArray generated by the model will look like this.

```
Float32 1 x 128 matrix
 [4.476562,1.179688,0.07141113,6.976562,-0.2858887,-7.378906,0.6445312,3.695312,1.399414,2.486328,-3.988281,-0.2636719,1.000977,-4.480469,-7.832031,1.59082,0.8515625,-1.296875,-1.435547,7.839844,5.851562,0.3701172,-2.492188,7.273438,2.404297,-3.3125,-5.699219,-0.6816406,0.2807617,-3.882812,-3.982422,5.339844,4.125,-3.871094,0.6225586,1.712891,-10.02344,0.7119141,4.472656,3.566406,-0.559082,-1.049805,-4.679688,10.07812,-1.459961,4.707031,-6.078125,1.675781,-0.6259766,2.519531,3.472656,-3.400391,-6.714844,-4.933594,-1.733398,1.095703,-6.15625,9.234375,3.693359,-9.492188,0.8637695,0.8203125,-2.814453,-4.4375,-1.092773,3.332031,0.1623535,3.583984,-11.25781,-0.9941406,-0.3491211,1.464844,-1.579102,4.558594,2.703125,4.601562,5.914062,-2.402344,-5.46875,-0.355957,11.39062,2.070312,-7.289062,-0.4470215,-0.1595459,9.148438,1.833008,-2.097656,-3.9375,6.699219,-4.347656,-6.835938,-1.179688,3.910156,-13.07812,-1.947266,-0.9238281,-0.949707,-4.398438,2.363281,4.421875,4.632812,2.607422,8.773438,0.9106445,9.21875,-14.0625,-1.301758,-4.875,0.6054688,6.496094,-2.021484,3.898438,-4.644531,0.9853516,7.253906,3.066406,-1.051758,-8.09375,-6.527344,3.890625,5.175781,0.3701172,-0.5683594,-1.341797,0.1497803,4.074219,0.5932617]
```

Any help would be appreciated <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store an Array of Primitives in **Realm**, and reconstruct your `MLMultiArray` from them.

```
class Student: Object {
    @objc dynamic var regNo : String = ""
    let faceMatrixValues = List<Float>()

    // Computed property
    var faceMatrix: MLMultiArray {
        try! MLMultiArray(faceMatrixValues.map { $0 })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. So to save the MLMultiArray to Realm I have to convert MLMultiArray to Float and then while loading I can reconstruct them? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is the only way I can think of doing it with Realm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question. do you know a way I can convert the above vector to float32?

Comment: I think you would have to slice/stride over the MLMultiArray, according to its shape.  Perhaps worthy of a separate question on SO?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @rbaldwin. I'll post it as a separate question.

Comment: I ran into one problem using this method. The faceMatrixValues takes a list of float values. So when I need to use student.faceMatrixValues.append(objectsIn: vector) where the vector is one MLMultiArray converted to a Float array. But I need to store an array of Float arrays, basically, every 120 vectors are one image. So I cant combine the float arrays into one huge array of 15360 values. 

Basically I need to store list of list<Float>(). Is this possible? 
@rbaldwin

Comment: @AneeshPrabu Please don't do this - lists of primitives are not fully supported; you can't use aggregate functions and they can't be filtered amongst other issues. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414134/filtering-realm-with-nested-subqueries/59446077#59446077) for another option.

Comment: @AneeshPrabu and more info on [github](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5334)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @rbaldwin answer you can store the MLMultiArray by converting it to one single Float Array of size 1x15360 instead of 120 [1x128] matrix. It'll be a long list of Float values but you can retrieve the same list in the form of [[Float]].

```
class Student: Object {
    @objc dynamic var regNo : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    let faceMatrixValues = List<Float>()

    var floatArray: [[Float]] {
        var resultArray = [Float]()
        for vector in faceMatrixValues {
            resultArray.append(vector)
        }
        return resultArray.chunked(into: 128)
    }
}
```

To retrieve it from realm use the below code.

```
let student = realm.objects(Student.self)
print("Loading [[Float]] from Realm...")

for res in student[0].floatArray {
    print(res)
}
```

The `resultArray.chunked(into: 128)` will split the single 15360 length array into 128 length float arrays. Using the below extension this function can be performed for any Array type.

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

In order to convert the [MLMultiArray] to [[Float]] we can use this Question I had previously asked [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61709079/convert-mlmultiarray-to-float).

Comment: Keep in mind that storing primites in List objects is not fully supported so for example, you can't filter for a specific Float value. Possibly more important, is you can't use aggregate functions - so suppose you want to get a average of the Float values (for example). The .average function doesn't work on lists so to do that they will have to be loaded into memory and iterated over. That's fine for small lists but if the size grows it could be an issue as it overrides the naturally lazy loading of Realm objects and can become a memory hog.